# Client server communication with Java Sockets

Tags: java, sockets

i built a program with client and server sockets in java that gets a number from the client, and multiply it by 2.
the code doesn't let me put a number in the client side.
code:

**Client:**

```
public class cli {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number,temp;
        Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1342);
        Scanner c1 = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("Enter any number");
        number = in.nextInt();
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
        p.println(number);
        temp = c1.nextInt();
        System.out.println(temp);
        in.close();
        s.close();
        c1.close();
    }
}
```

**Server:**

```
public class ser {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

        ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(1342);
        Socket ss = s1.accept();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(ss.getInputStream());
        int number = sc.nextInt();

        int temp = number * 2;

        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());
        p.println(temp);
        ss.close();
        sc.close();
        s1.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem isn't well described. What happens when you run it? What do you mean by "doesn't let me"?

Comment: What is the stack trace you get. I tried the same code and it worked okay !

Answer (score 1):

You should use [DataInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) to read your `int` and [DataOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) to write it, it is more appropriate in your case than a `Scanner`. You should also consider using [try-with-resourses](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to properly close your resources.

Your code will then be much easier to read and to maintain which is the best way to avoid bugs.

**Server:**

```
public class ser {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        try (ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(1342);
             Socket ss = s1.accept();
             DataInputStream sc = new DataInputStream(ss.getInputStream());
             DataOutputStream p = new DataOutputStream(ss.getOutputStream());
        ) {
            p.writeInt(sc.readInt() * 2);
        }
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
public class cli {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1342);
            DataInputStream c1 = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream p = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        ){
            System.out.println("Enter any number");
            int number = in.nextInt();

            p.writeInt(number);
            System.out.println(c1.readInt());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter any number
12
24
```